# ejabberd xmpp connection not maintained

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I've created a web-chat application using jQuery and Ejabberd (example from Professional XMPP Book). For this application, I've implemented anonymous authentication (was a requirement). 
When user visits the site, according to his username, I authenticate and give access to XMPP Chat. Using shared roster, he can see all other users and chat with them. 
However, when page is refreshed or moved to another page, I need to create a new connection again and it hangs on 'Connecting' state. 
How can I solve this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything strange in Ejabebrd log?

Answer (score 0):

You should investigate your client code, because it should not happen. I did this many times personally with success.

However, closing and reconnecting on each page is not a good practice when writing an HTTP client and you will have trouble scaling your application.
You should investigate way to reattach to existing connection.